# Can I Unzip a file in Azure Blob storage?

Tags: azure, unzip, azure-blob-storage

My application requires to unzip a zip file located in Azure's blob storage.
Is unzipping supported in Azure blob storage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Out of the box no, but you can keep any binary data you want in blob storage and use `myBlob.DownloadToStream(myStream)` and then use your choice of zip/unzip libraries to unzip the stream.

Comment: I cann't unzip it. Could you please help me in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556456/azure-java-read-and-unzip-a-file-which-is-saved-in-azure-storage-and-encoded-b

Comment: I suspect the problem will be somewhere in the way it's either being encoded or decoded rather than something specific to Azure.  I don't know much about the tools you're using, so I'm not much help to you, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**One way** is to create an Azure Function with blob trigger, and the function would need to handle the logic to unzip the zip file. This solution is dependent on your code.

**Second way** is to create an Azure Logic App, with Blob trigger, then use connectors to unzip the zipped files. Please refer video: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAr20GBQayL-nFPWFnUHNAA