# Azure, Java: Read and Unzip a file which is saved in Azure Storage (Blobs) and encoded by Avro

Tags: java, json, azure, avro, unzip

I have a file in Azure Storage which is zipped and then encoded by Avro as Blob. I read it and decode it as you see in the following code:

```
public static int decodeAvroFile(String avroFile) throws Exception {
        GenericDatumReader<Object> reader=new GenericDatumReader<Object>();
        org.apache.avro.file.FileReader<Object>  fileReader=  DataFileReader.openReader(new File(avroFile),reader);
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            Schema schema=fileReader.getSchema();
            DatumWriter<Object> writer=new GenericDatumWriter<Object>(schema);
            JsonEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema, os);
            for (Object datum : fileReader)     writer.write(datum,encoder);
            encoder.flush();
            SaveJasonInDB saveJson = new SaveJasonInDB();
            saveJson.zipJsonParser(os, avroFile + "-decodedFile");
        }
            finally {
                fileReader.close();
              }
            return 0;
}
```

After that, I have to pars it to get the content in zip file via JSON:

```
public void zipJsonParser(ByteArrayOutputStream os,String jsonFile) throws ParseException, IOException {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); 
        String st = os.toString();
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(st);
        System.out.println(json.get("EnqueuedTimeUtc"));
        JSONObject body =  (JSONObject) json.get("Body");
        createZipFile((String) body.get("bytes"), jsonFile);
    }
```

Finaly I want to unzip the zip file:

```
public void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException {
        File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
        if (!destDir.exists()) {
            destDir.mkdir();
        }
        ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
        ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        // iterates over entries in the zip file
        while (entry != null) {
            String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                // if the entry is a file, extracts it
                extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
            } else {
                // if the entry is a directory, make the directory
                File dir = new File(filePath);
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            zipIn.closeEntry();
            entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        }
        zipIn.close();
    }
    private void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath) throws IOException {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
        }
        bos.close();
    }
```

Everything is ok when I try the last part of code to unzip a normal zip file. But in this example, we have to decode Avro file and extract the zip file from a JSON element, it doesn't work. You see a part of JSON here:

> {"EnqueuedTimeUtc":"2017-11-28T09:45:55.4560000Z","Properties":{},"SystemProperties":{"connectionDeviceId":"firstSAM","contentEncoding":"","connectionDeviceGenerationId":"636451410108166633","contentType":"application/json","connectionAuthMethod":"{\"scope\":\"hub\",\"type\":\"sas\",\"issuer\":\"iothub\",\"acceptingIpFilterRule\":null}","enqueuedTime":"2017-11-28T09:45:55.4560000Z"},"Body":{"bytes":"PK\u0003\u0004\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000SK|K\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000

Could you please help me??

Comment: Have you encountered any exceptions? Would you please post trace log to let me help you solve the issue?

Comment: NO. I didn't have any exception. It finds just the root folder(In Zip file there is a root folder and some relevant files) but doesn't recognize any file.